# Differential equations that have non-sinusoidal periodic solutions

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, periodic-functions

Examples help but I mostly just want to know what the criteria is for an equation to give non-sinusoidal periodic functions as solutions. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Periodic_function the first image here is non-sinusoidal and it looks like it's not symmetric for the part it repeats.

An example of a sinusoidal solution to an equation is: finding the solution to $\frac{d^2x}{dt^2} = -\frac{kx}{m}$ (SHM).

I can't think of anything that would give such solutions. (I guess I should also ask, are there methods of obtaining such solutions?)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Non-trigonometric Continuous Periodic Functions](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/935840/non-trigonometric-continuous-periodic-functions)

Comment: I know non-trig periodic functions exist I'm wondering about differential equations that have solutions of them.

Comment: Check https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Limit_cycle and https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Van_der_Pol_oscillator

Comment: $a x''(t) + b x'(t)+ c x(t)$ has as solution $x(t) = \sum_k \beta_k e^{\rho_k t}$ where $\rho_k$ are the roots of the polynomial $a X^2 + bX + c$. from this you can easily see which homogeneous differential equations have periodic and non-periodic solutions https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Characteristic_equation_(calculus)

Comment: There is the so-called [Poincaré–Bendixson theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Poincar%C3%A9%E2%80%93Bendixson_theorem), which gives you a class of differential equations with periodic but not necessarily sinusoidal solutions.

Comment: You can find examples amongst the theta functions. See, for example, http://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC336999/pdf/pnas00155-0220.pdf

Comment: Thank you for all of these examples. I cannot comprehend most of them but I appreciate it nonetheless.

Comment: You can check Lotka–Volterra equations: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lotka%E2%80%93Volterra_equations#:~:text=The%20Lotka%E2%80%93Volterra%20equations%2C%20also,and%20the%20other%20as%20prey.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

While there are very few differential equations we know how to solve, whenever the second derivative of a variable $\left(\dfrac{d^2x}{dt^2}\right)$ is proportional to the inverse of the variable itself $(x)$ we guess that the solution to the differential equation is most likely sinusoidal. Why?

Well say we have $x(t)=\sin(kt+\phi)$. Then, $x'(t)=k\cos(kt+\phi)$ and $x''(t)=-k^2\sin(kt+\phi)$. Thus, $x''(t)=-k^2x(t)$ and we have that the second derivative of the function is proportional to the original function itself.

Very similarly to the Hooke's Law case, the wave equation has a sinusoidal solution to the differential equation.

Comment: I think you mean to the variable itself. Not the inverse.